# Using Yubikey SDK to Programmatically Eject/Insert a Yubikey (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, yubikey

I'm writing a C# app that will be used to program several hundred Yubikeys (set lock code, remove interfaces, etc.), so I want to make it as efficient as possible.

Is there any way using methods in the SDK to programmatically eject/insert the Yubikey? Some of the code I'm writing seems to require the device to be refreshed this way.  I note that the Graphical YKMAN-GUI.exe and the commandline ykman.exe both do this, so it's certainly possible.

I've tried using ChatGPT, but it seems to keep pointing me to classes and methods that don't even exist, so I figure I try real humans to answer this next.

Comment: those tools might use the hardware apis to disable the device